# I cant get minecraft 1.6.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft it says I can't play games because I have to update my client. Also, 2 of the servers say X-1.6.2 so am I in 1.6.3? It also says that I can't play some servers because they are 1.6.4. How can I update Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [minecraft.net/download](http://minecraft.net/download) and download the latest launcher, which should be the updated new 1.6 launcher, which will allow you to update to 1.6 after you input your username and password into the new launcher after opening it.